# FLS Update for id field

Tags: security-review, field-level-security, security-scanner

In the case of record update, we will use the Id field to specify Id value. How to check FLS for Id field. I have already check isAccesible method. But still, it shows in the security scanner. Is it a false negative?

Comment: Did you add check for that sObject isUpdateable

Comment: So what you are saying is I want to check whether the particular object is updatable in Id field. That's a good one. will check and let you know. Thanks...

Comment: Yes , Its a false negative. !!